# How to reset selectable fields in Django app using jQuery

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I was recently asked to take over a partially-written Django app.  The Python, I can handle, but I have no Javascript experience and this uses jQuery to do a bunch of form manipulations.  Upon form submission, the form itself should be reset to a pristine state.  However, while the reset appears to mostly work, any select fields (single or multiple), appear on the web page to retain their old values.

The fields are defined something like this in the Django app

```
business_unit = forms.ChoiceField(
    label='Business unit',
    required=True,
    choices=BUSINESS_UNIT_CHOICES,
    widget=forms.Select(attrs={'data-placeholder':'Select one', 'data-minimum-results-for-search':'10', 'data-tags':'true'}),
)
```

And the reset is performed via

```
$('#custom-form').trigger('reset');
```

All the simple text fields are cleared.  The select fields values are actually cleared (they contain no values), but on the web form, they appear to still be populated.  Any suggestions what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following: In addition to your reset, add this to your code to iterate through all select fields and set them to the first option (usually this is the option with a "Please select" placeholder).

```
 let selects = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
 for(let i=0; i < selects.length; i++){
    selects[i].selectedIndex = 0;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @matthias_h, that probably would have worked if the code weren't using the select2 plugin as noted in the answer I just posted.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my question, I am a total Javascript novice.  Today I learned about plugins, in this case one called select2.  Once I understood that, it was as simple as adding the following after the form reset

```
$( "select" ).each(function( index ) {
    $( this ).trigger('change');
});
```